# Python - Remove quotes and double minus using replace

Tags: python

Given a string such as

```
--"I like salami. "-I want to walk to the shops"
```

How can I return the string such as

```
I like salami. I want to walk to the shops.
```

I can alter each individually but when I use '-"' it fails.

**Quotes**

```
b = '"'

for char in b:
    solution = MyString.replace(char,"")

#output --I like salami. -I want to walk to the shops
```

**Minus**

```
b = '-'

for char in b:
    solution = MyString.replace(char,"")

#output "I like salami. "I want to walk to the shops"
```

**Together**

```
MyString = '--"I like salami. "-I want to walk to the shops"'

b = '"-'

for char in b:
    print(MyString.replace(char,""))

#output "I like salami. "I want to walk to the shops"
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Apply first `replace()`, assign the result to a new string variable and apply second `replace()` to this new string.

Comment: `replace` doesn't change the string, it returns a new string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.replace(oldstr, newstr)` method will help you, and it is simple and daisy-chainable. So...

```
MyString = MyString.replace('"', '').replace('-', '')
```

Note that the `.replace()` method only replaces substrings in one shot. It cannot do individual characters. For that, you could do it with a regular expression, but that's more complicated. That module can be accessed with `import re`.  You could use:

```
MyString = re.sub('["-]', '', MyString)
```

Also, on a sidenote... Quoting can be tricky. But there are FOUR different ways you can quote something: in a pair of single quotes, a pair of double quotes, or a pair of triple single-quotes or triple double-quotes. So, all the below are strings in Python:

```
'hello'
"Don't you think"  # string with an apostrophe is easily in double quotes
'''that this is a really really..'''
"""long quote?  Hey!
    this quote is actually more than one line long!"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
MyString = '--"I like salami. "-I want to walk to the shops"'
MyString = MyString.replace('"',"")
MyString = MyString.replace('-',"")
print MyString
#output: I like salami. I want to walk to the shops
```

Or you can use Regular expression and do it like this:

```
import re
MyString = '--"I like salami. "-I want to walk to the shops"'
MyString = re.sub('["-]', '', MyString)
print MyString
#output: I like salami. I want to walk to the shops
```

Remember to install *re* if it doesn't exist already. Tell me if there are any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Python `string.replace` doesn't do an in-place replace, but instead returns a new string which contains the [replacement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm). Since you are not using the return value from the first replace, it is discarded and the second iteration of your loop with the character `-` replaces *just this character* and not `"`, in the original string. For the intended effect, you can use the following snippet:

```
MyString = '--"I like salami. "-I want to walk to the shops"'
b = '"-'
for char in b:
    MyString = MyString.replace(char,"")
print(MyString)
#Outputs: I like salami. I want to walk to the shops
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: MyString = '--"I like salami. "-I want to walk to the shops"'
In [2]: MyString.replace('-', '').replace('"', '')
Out[2]: 'I like salami. I want to walk to the shops'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is little different approach using beautiful lambda function:

```
word='--"I like salami. "-I want to walk to the shops"'
print("".join(list(map(lambda x:x if x!='-' and x!='"' else '',word))))
```

output:

```
I like salami. I want to walk to the shops
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using regex:

```
import re
str = '--"I like salami. "-I want to walk to the shops"'
print re.sub("[-\"]", repl="", string=str)
```

**output:**

```
I like salami. I want to walk to the shops
```